# Error in reading xml

Tags: php, xml, foreach, xmlreader

I have an xml sheet of some hotel details, but when I try to read all data, its not showing all datas, just repeating the first hotel name or hotel data. Below have the link to xml code.

[myxmlfile](http://www.medhyaftravel.com/api/api3/myxmlfile.xml)

and I have tried this code to retrieve data,

```
            $availabilityrs = simplexml_load_string($response3);
            $hotel = $availabilityrs->hotels->hotel;
            $hotel1 = $availabilityrs->hotels->hotel;
            $room_nodes = $hotel->rooms->room;
            foreach ($hotel1 as $room) {
                echo "Hotel Name: ".$hotel['name']."\n"; ?><br /><?php
                echo "Hotel Category: ".$hotel['categoryName']."\n"; ?><br /><?php
                echo "Hotel Destination: ".$hotel['destinationName']."\n"; ?><br /><?php
                echo "Room Name: ".$room['name']."\n"; ?><br /><br /><?php
            }
```

and the result is like

> Hotel Name: Ibis Hotel Salmiya  Hotel Category: 3 STARS  Hotel
>   Destination: Kuwait  Room Name: Ibis Hotel Salmiya
>
> Hotel Name: Ibis Hotel Salmiya  Hotel Category: 3 STARS  Hotel
>   Destination: Kuwait  Room Name: Jumeirah Messilah Beach Hotel & Spa
>
> Hotel Name: Ibis Hotel Salmiya  Hotel Category: 3 STARS  Hotel
>   Destination: Kuwait  Room Name: The Regency Hotel
>
> Hotel Name: Ibis Hotel Salmiya  Hotel Category: 3 STARS  Hotel
>   Destination: Kuwait  Room Name: Times Square Suites
>
> Hotel Name: Ibis Hotel Salmiya  Hotel Category: 3 STARS  Hotel
>   Destination: Kuwait  Room Name: Ibis Sharq
>
> Hotel Name: Ibis Hotel Salmiya  Hotel Category: 3 STARS  Hotel
>   Destination: Kuwait  Room Name: Mövenpick Kuwait
>
> Hotel Name: Ibis Hotel Salmiya  Hotel Category: 3 STARS  Hotel
>   Destination: Kuwait  Room Name: JW Marriott Kuwait
>
> Hotel Name: Ibis Hotel Salmiya  Hotel Category: 3 STARS  Hotel
>   Destination: Kuwait  Room Name: Radisson Blu Hotel Kuwait
>
> Hotel Name: Ibis Hotel Salmiya  Hotel Category: 3 STARS  Hotel
>   Destination: Kuwait  Room Name: Safir Residence
>
> Hotel Name: Ibis Hotel Salmiya  Hotel Category: 3 STARS  Hotel
>   Destination: Kuwait  Room Name: Carlton Tower Hotel Kuwait
>
> Hotel Name: Ibis Hotel Salmiya  Hotel Category: 3 STARS  Hotel
>   Destination: Kuwait  Room Name: Courtyard By Marriott Kuwait
>
> Hotel Name: Ibis Hotel Salmiya  Hotel Category: 3 STARS  Hotel
>   Destination: Kuwait  Room Name: Oasis Hotel Kuwait
>
> Hotel Name: Ibis Hotel Salmiya  Hotel Category: 3 STARS  Hotel
>   Destination: Kuwait  Room Name: The Palms Beach Hotel & Spa
>
> Hotel Name: Ibis Hotel Salmiya  Hotel Category: 3 STARS  Hotel
>   Destination: Kuwait  Room Name: Marina Hotel
>
> Hotel Name: Ibis Hotel Salmiya  Hotel Category: 3 STARS  Hotel
>   Destination: Kuwait  Room Name: Al Manshar Rotana Hotel
>
> Hotel Name: Ibis Hotel Salmiya  Hotel Category: 3 STARS  Hotel
>   Destination: Kuwait  Room Name: Symphony Style Hotel Kuwait
>
> Hotel Name: Ibis Hotel Salmiya  Hotel Category: 3 STARS  Hotel
>   Destination: Kuwait  Room Name: Millennium Hotel & Convention Centre
>   Kuwait
>
> Hotel Name: Ibis Hotel Salmiya  Hotel Category: 3 STARS  Hotel
>   Destination: Kuwait  Room Name: Le Royal Kuwait
>
> Hotel Name: Ibis Hotel Salmiya  Hotel Category: 3 STARS  Hotel
>   Destination: Kuwait  Room Name: Le Royal Tower Kuwait
>
> Hotel Name: Ibis Hotel Salmiya  Hotel Category: 3 STARS  Hotel
>   Destination: Kuwait  Room Name: Ramada Kuwait Hotel
>
> Hotel Name: Ibis Hotel Salmiya  Hotel Category: 3 STARS  Hotel
>   Destination: Kuwait  Room Name: Crowne Plaza Kuwait
>
> Hotel Name: Ibis Hotel Salmiya  Hotel Category: 3 STARS  Hotel
>   Destination: Kuwait  Room Name: Al Jahra Copthone Hotel & Resort
>
> Hotel Name: Ibis Hotel Salmiya  Hotel Category: 3 STARS  Hotel
>   Destination: Kuwait  Room Name: Best Western Plus Mahboula
>
> Hotel Name: Ibis Hotel Salmiya  Hotel Category: 3 STARS  Hotel
>   Destination: Kuwait  Room Name: New Park Hotel
>
> Hotel Name: Ibis Hotel Salmiya  Hotel Category: 3 STARS  Hotel
>   Destination: Kuwait  Room Name: Flora Park Apartment
>
> Hotel Name: Ibis Hotel Salmiya  Hotel Category: 3 STARS  Hotel
>   Destination: Kuwait  Room Name: HOLIDAY INN KUWAIT AL THURAYA CITY

How to get all the data of hotel details

Comment: and your question is ?

Comment: How to retrieve all hotel details in foreach loop?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this i have made few changes:

```
$xml = "http://www.medhyaftravel.com/api/api3/myxmlfile.xml";
$xml = preg_replace(
                  '/^(<\?[xX][mM][lL]\s+[^\?\>]+encoding\s*=\s*([\'"]))utf-16\2/u',
                  '\1utf-8\2', file_get_contents($xml));
$xmlcont = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

foreach($xmlcont as $url) { 

$hotel = $url->hotel;

foreach($hotel as $hot){

echo $hot['name']; echo "</br>"; echo $hot['categoryName'];echo "</br>";

$roomtest =  $hot->rooms->room;  echo $roomtest['name'];

}
 }
```

**OR**

```
$xml = "http://www.medhyaftravel.com/api/api3/myxmlfile.xml";
$xml = preg_replace(
                  '/^(<\?[xX][mM][lL]\s+[^\?\>]+encoding\s*=\s*([\'"]))utf-16\2/u',
                  '\1utf-8\2', file_get_contents($xml));
 $availabilityrs = simplexml_load_string($xml);
 foreach($availabilityrs as $url) {

$hotel = $url->hotel;

foreach($hotel as $hot){


$roomtest =  $hot->rooms->room;

echo "Hotel Name: ".$hot['name']."<br/>";
echo "Hotel Category: ".$hot['categoryName']."<br/>";
echo "Hotel Destination: ".$hot['destinationName']."<br/>";
echo "Room Name: ".$roomtest['name']."<br/><br/><br/>";



}   

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assigning the `$hotel` variable outside the loop. It will not change while you iterate it.

```
$availabilityrs = simplexml_load_string($response3);
$hotels = $availabilityrs->hotels->hotel;
foreach ($hotels as $hotel) {
   echo "Hotel Name: ".$hotel['name']."\n"; 
   //...
}
```

SimpleXMLs syntax magic allows you to treat it as a node list (for `foreach()`) or as a single element (first of the list).